# Access Environment Variables through vite-react and GCP Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, client-side

I have a React application that is Dockerized and hosted on Google Cloud Build. I have set environment variables on the Cloud Build, but I am unable to access them within my React application. What am I doing wrong and how can I access these environment variables in my React application?

steps:

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  env:

  - > - 

    -"VITE_PUBLIC_KEY={$_VITE_PUBLIC_KEY}",
    -"VITE_SERVICE_ID={$_VITE_SERVICE_ID}",
    -"VITE_TEMPLATE_ID={$_VITE_TEMPLATE_ID}"
    args:
  - build
  - '--no-cache'
  - '-t'
  - 'image_name'
  - .
  - '-f'
  - Dockerfile.prod
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args:

  - push
  - 'image_name'
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args:

  - run
  - deploy
  - bob
  - '--image'
  - 'image_name'
  - '--region'
  - $_DEPLOY_REGION
  - '--allow-unauthenticated'
  - '--platform'
  - $_PLATFORM
    timeout: 600s

this is the yaml file:

I dont have a backend solution, I just want to be able to access 3 enviromnent variables within my application on client side. without declaring a .env file.

Tried declaring the enviroments in Cloud Run as well as declaring in the cloudbuild.yaml file. It works on aws but a different problem arises on aws.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to hardcode the environment variables directly into your React code. This is not recommended as it could lead to security vulnerabilities and make it difficult to change the values in the future without re-deploying the entire application. Additionally, it would not be a true solution to accessing the environment variables as they would not be dynamically set at runtime.

Comment: Its sensitive information, I dont want it to be in the bundle.js file when the app i being build. Therefore the solution of writing the environment variables in google cloud. I've declared them in secret manager but cant seem to access them in the actual build.